# How to display distinct value from formControlName, (moduleGroupName here) in angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

[enter link description here](https://codebeautify.org/typescript-formatter-online/y2208d78a)
HTML Code of the following (Configuration and Performance are modules here)

```html
<div formArrayName="permissionForm">
  <div *ngFor="let subModule of permissionForm.value; let i=index;
              [formGroupName]="i">

    <input type="text" readonly formControlName="moduleGroupName" /></div>
</div>
(Below is the ts code)
```

**TS Code :**

```js
BuildFormDynamic(module, moduleGroup) {
  const m = module;
  return this.fb.group({
    'id': [m.id],
    'moduleGroupName': [moduleGroup],
    'subModules': [m.name],
    'view': [],
    'add': [],
    'edit': [],
    'delete': []
  })
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1OVK.png)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: As u can see in the image, module Configuration is repeated 3 times, and Performance also is repeated 3 times. But I want to Display it only once. How to do it?

Comment: You need to post more code. Where is `BuildFormDynamic` called